# Running examples from scikit-learn tutorials

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, prediction

I am new to scikit-learn. I went through the examples given in the docs and I downloaded the script for recognizing images of hand-written digits. When I made the script to run on my laptop, I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\plot_digits_classification.py", line 22, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in<module>
    from .base import clone
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
  from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
   from .validation import (as_float_array,
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 16, in <module>
   from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 324, in <module>
   from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
   from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
  from . import _iterative
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help me. Also, I want to know if I want to load data for prediction, how should I do that? For example, if I want to test a hand written digit that is stored somewhere on my disk, how to prepare that data for loading and passing into this model for prediction?

Comment: Can you add the code you're trying to run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed older version of numpy,that's the problem. If you have installed scikit-learn using windows binaries, then you must first install numpy+mkl from the windows binaries site. It is a prerequisite for scikit-learn.

Comment: Maybe try the Anaconda Python distribution (https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's got a great package manager that takes care of all dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've got to install the [module,](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) for example with the `pip` package manager. Perhaps you could install anaconda, which is highly recommended

Comment: installed already

Comment: Got more than one python install, an older one not in path?